# Meaning of "offen balkon machen"?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context, slang

> ... bin ja verheiratet und **mache viel offen balkon**

This is said in the tv show Stromberg (00:26 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUcS4DrExOo)). What does "mache viel offen balkon" means, if that is really what is said.

Comment: I doubt someone says that, it makes no sense. It would help if you could link the video in question, preferably with a timecode.

Comment: @Janka video added.

Comment: It's *… und mach viel auf'm Balkon* – *und mache viel auf dem Balkon*. Such contractions are common.

Comment: And if you wonder about him singing *Zigeunerjunge …* that's a well-known 1960ies Schlager sung by *Alexandra*. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGdyA77tN8w

Comment: @Janka And what is meant by "mache viel auf dem Balkon" in that context?

Comment: Nothing, he made that up. He found that kind of interview very silly, which is very German of him. That's how the author characterizes him.

Comment: @Janka so no sexual connotation? Cos he says that after saying I am married.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98179/discussion-between-janka-and-sasan).

Comment: The word "Zigeuner" kann be quite offensive in certain contexts these days.

Comment: @rackandboneman Does anyone really care except the ludicrous PC brigade? Quite a pest nowadays, I agree. Anway: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Balkonien "The mythical country where one takes one's holiday, situated on the Terrasse."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He says

> ich mache viel auf dem Balkon

In the context of this conversation he is truly trying to say that he spends a good amount of his free time on the balcony. Some people grow plants, have BBQs or just sit on their balcony.

Even though he mentions that he is married, there is no sexual connotation.

*Of course he doesn’t take the situation very seriously. So it’s probably simply a lie...*

Comment: Probably worth adding that in his dialect, "auf dem" is "auffem", which OP confused with "offen".

Comment: BBQ on a balcony is one of those illustrative examples which look nice in language textbooks, in reality it is often an invitation for local fire brigade.